# substracting 1 years to a date php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to select something from my database but I do a chart, so for comparating In eed the same value but for the previous years.

Also I've done something like that:

```
$query254="
  SELECT SUM(honoraires) 
  FROM versements 
  WHERE `date_reception`=DATE_SUB(".$dates3[$i3].", INTERVAL 365 DAY)";

  $resultat254 = mysql_query($query254) or die(mysql_error());
  $rowing254 = mysql_fetch_array($resultat254); ?>
```

The thing is that it does not work, In fact it select the values for the same year. Without substracting the 365 days.

So I do not know how to do.

Receive all my Utmost Respect.

SP.

Comment: so you want to do **TODAY'S DATE - 365 days**? to get the starting date for a SQL query?

Comment: not today but the date that is $dates3[$i3] (it comes from an array).

Comment: Goes slightly awry when there's a leap year

Comment: Does it have to be done in mysql instead of php?

Comment: how can I pass this problem? Is there a day to do the same but with no 365 days but just 1 year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query254="SELECT 
SUM(honoraires) 
FROM 
versements 
WHERE 
`date_reception`=date(".mysql_real_escape_string($dates3[$i3])." - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It worked almost perfectfullu. I just had to retire the mysql_real_eascape_string cause it has added many slashes to the daye like 2011/-/05/-/05 but without that function It works fine. Thank you verry much for your help. Kind Regards SP

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` should not be adding slashes like that. You're probably using `addslashes` somewhere.

Comment: Please make sure you are escaping the input properly to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: in fact it comes from a mysql but there is no data save. You know I have 2 input for datesthen it display generated statistics using highcharts library, but there is no save. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind doing it in php before you put it into the MySQL query. Just do this:

```
$tempdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dates3[$i3] . ' -1 year'));
$query254="
  SELECT SUM(honoraires) 
  FROM versements 
  WHERE `date_reception`='{$tempdate}'";
```

Comment: Dear Sir, Actually it change all the date to 1970-01-01. WHen i Do echo query  SELECT SUM(honoraires) 
  FROM versements 
  WHERE `date_reception`='1970-01-01'

Comment: I was assuming that $dates3[$i3] was already in "Y-m-d" format. If not please let us know what format it is in.

Comment: It is un YYYY-MM-dD but I ve done like thorsten told me. Thank you so much for your help